# How to pass subtype of model to action from main action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action that is receiving a model of type:

```
ExchangeBooksSearchViewModel : ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel
```

so when I post back I have info in that model pertaining to authors etc. So I pass that down into the view:

```
    public ActionResult Books(ExchangeBooksSearchViewModel searchModel, int? page)
{
    ..
    return View("Index", searchModel);
}
```

..

```
@model Ui.Mvc.Models.ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = metaExchange.Index_PageTitle;
    ViewBag.ActionName = "Index";
}
@section InlineTitle {<h2>@metaExchange.Index_InlineTitle</h2>
} 
@section SearchArea { @Html.Partial("_ItemsSearch_ManagerPartial", Model)}  

@Html.Partial("_ItemsList_AjaxPartial", Model)

@section HiddenPostFields {  }  

@section scripts{}
```

And then within _ItemsSearch_ManagerPartial I call an action to display the appropriate search Ui for the model:

```
 <div id="AdvancedCategorySearch">
                        @Html.Action("NonAjaxPostbackCategorySearchDisplay", Model)
                    </div>
```

..

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult NonAjaxPostbackCategorySearchDisplay(ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel searchModel)
        {
            if (searchModel.CategoryAction == "Books")
            {
                return PartialView("_ItemsSearch_Books", new ExchangeBooksSearchViewModel());
            }

            if (searchModel.CategoryAction == "Computers")
            {
                return PartialView("_ItemsSearch_Computers", new ExchangeComputersSearchViewModel());
            }

            return PartialView("_ItemsSearch_Basic", new ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel());
        }
```

The problem is that by the time I get  to

```
NonAjaxPostbackCategorySearchDisplay(ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel searchModel)
```

I only have the base type ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel to work with even if I attempt to cast::

```
ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel as ExchangeBooksSearchViewModel
```

I get null. This i don't understand. I realise that my view have a model type of

```
@model Ui.Mvc.Models.ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel
```

The point of which is allow sub-types to pass in for the generic function of the view but since this is all still happening on the server I don't understand where my sub-type got stripped down into a base type?

In "normal" c# you can pass around an interface and then cast as necessary into the type you "know" you need at the appropriate point. I suspect this has something to do with automatic model binding but not certain and would like to know how to get around it otherwise i suspect I'm in for ([n] * search models) copy/paste of code changing only for model type.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The viewmodel on the view is incorrect.
 you should use:

```
@model Ui.Mvc.Models.ExchangeBookSearchViewModel
```

ExchangeBasicSearchViewModel should just act as an abstract class

Comment: If I make it Ui.Mvc.Models.ExchangeBookSearchViewModel then what do I do with Ui.Mvc.Models.ExchangeComputerSearchViewModel? Copy /paste?

Comment: what is that? you havent mentioned in it the question